# Getting TypeError:"Descriptors cannot be installed directly" when running MediaPipe

Tags: python, mediapipe

I am trying to run a script using mediapipe but I am getting this error: TypeError:"Descriptors cannot be installed directly"

If this call came from a _pb2.py file, your generated code is out of date and must be regenerated with protoc >= 3.19.0.

If you cannot immediately regenerate your protos, some other possible workarounds are:

1. Downgrade the protobuf package to 3.20.x or lower.
2. Set PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=python (but this will use pure-Python parsing and will be much slower).

My Current Version of python is 3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution, at least for now, is in the error message:

> Downgrade the protobuf package to 3.20.x or lower.

So add a pinned requirement to protobuf in your requirements.txt:

```
protobuf==3.20.0
```